# H2 database Server mode created from Playframework not accessible from SQuirll

Tags: jdbc, h2, playframework-2.3

I have running H2 database locally in server mode.

```
TCP server running at tcp://192.168.159.1:9092 (others can connect)
```

When I connect to H2 instance via Playframework aplication using this configuration

```
db.default.url="jdbc:h2:tcp://192.168.159.1:9092/~/test3"
db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.default.username="sa"
db.default.password="sa"
```

Everything is fine database is created, evolution scripts are triggered but I cannot connect to that database using for example SQuirell. I keep getting 
this error:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Wrong user name or password [28000-192]
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:144)
at org.h2.engine.Engine.validateUserAndPassword(Engine.java:336)
at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSessionAndValidate(Engine.java:162)
at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:137)
at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.run(TcpServerThread.java:148)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Same is happenig when database is created outside Play, then in Play i'm getting same error. Is this some bug in 2.3.10 ( version of Play)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Play 2.3.x JDBC datasource is managed by BoneCP

## Correctly define User name

db.default.user=sa

So I used settings from more recent version
Play framework 2.5.x is using HikaryCP where this would be correct
db.default.username=sa